# React - TypeScript - MUI Tabs - Getting an Overload Error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, tabs

I am trying to create a component using MUI Tabs,

```
<Box>
    <Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange} variant='fullWidth'>
        {RoomTabs.map((tab, index) => (
            <Tab label={tab.label} value={tab.id} key={index} icon={tab.icon}/>
        ))}
    </Tabs>
    
</Box>
```

RoomTabs is an array of objects (with a "custom" Type)

VSCode is warning me, and when I Save (Local Server), the page pops up with the following error.

> ERROR in src/pages/system/rooms/Room.tsx:19:67
> TS2769: No overload matches this call.
> Overload 1 of 3, '(props: { href: string; } & { children?: null | undefined; classes?: Partial | undefined; disabled?: boolean | undefined; disableFocusRipple?: boolean | undefined; ... 5 more ...; wrapped?: boolean | undefined; } & Omit<...> & CommonProps & Omit<...>): Element', gave the following error.
> Type 'ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'string | ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor> | undefined'.
> Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor> | undefined'.
> Overload 2 of 3, '(props: { component: ElementType; } & { children?: null | undefined; classes?: Partial | undefined; disabled?: boolean | undefined; ... 6 more ...; wrapped?: boolean | undefined; } & Omit<...> & CommonProps & Omit<...>): Element | null', gave the following error.
> Type 'ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'string | ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor> | undefined'.
> Overload 3 of 3, '(props: DefaultComponentProps<ExtendButtonBaseTypeMap<TabTypeMap<{}, "div">>>): Element | null', gave the following error.
> Type 'ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'string | ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor> | undefined'.
> 17 |         
> 18 |             {RoomTabs.map((tab, index) => (
> 19 |                 
> |                                                                   ^^^^
> 20 |             ))}
> 21 |

I am trying to figure out how to get around this.  I assume it is because there is a potential for "tab.icon" to be undefined.

When I clear the error in the browser, my icons and tabs work as expected.

Just trying to better understand what might be happening.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like the Tab Icon element does not want a ReactNode, but a ReactElement.

Not really sure what the difference is, but I will go down the path to find out.